# Factoring an unusual polynomial

Tags: factoring

Hello I was presented today with a logarithmic problem. After computing the calculations in order to solve for $x$ we had to factor the following equation (no calculator allowed). I am a somewhat stumped due to the numbers. Is there an ingenious way of solving it?

$35^3$ = $x^2 + 70x$

Comment: This is a second degree polynomial and you can find both roots...

Comment: By factoring the equation presumably you mean to put all the nonzero terms on one side of the equation, and then factor the resulting polynomial (as equal to zero).  The idea is simplified if you consider allocating one each of the factors of $35$ to the two first degree factors' constant terms.  That leaves one remaining factor of $35$ to split between them, so as to get a result that is twice $35$.

Comment: maybe use $(x+35)^2 = x^2 + 70x + 35^2 = x^2 + 70 x +1225$

Comment: so $$(x+35)^2 = 35^3 + 35^2 = 35^2 \cdot (35+1) = 35^2 \cdot 6^2 = 210^2$$

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$x^2 + 70x - 35^3 = 0 \label{eq1A}$$

Using the quadratic formula, you can get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
x & = \frac{-70 \pm \sqrt{70^2 + 4(35^3)}}{2} \\
& = \frac{-70 \pm \sqrt{70^2 + (2)(35)(2)(35)(35)}}{2} \\
& = \frac{-70 \pm \sqrt{70^2(1 + 35)}}{2} \\
& = \frac{-70 \pm 70(6)}{2} \\
& = 35(-1 \pm 6) \\
& = -245 \; \text{ or } \; 175
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Answer (score 1):

After rearranging, you get a quadratic. Note that the discriminant of this quadratic is $ 70^2 + 4(1)(35^3) = 4(35)^2(1+35)= (2^2)(35^2)(6^2)$, a perfect square.